# code igniter - one to many child join?

Tags: mysql, join, codeigniter-2

Hi Guys I have two tables table B has a many to 1 relationship with table A

```
TableA        TableB
id  name       id   value
1  basketA     1    10
2  basketB     1    5 
               1    7
               2    7
               2    3
```

etc.. 
now 
    $query = $this->db->get('TableA');
    return $query->result_array();

returns the A fields obviously but how can I do a join so it will return A-Field along with the sum of the B-Items for that field?

eg. in the result array

```
BasketA 22
BasketB 10
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select A.id,A.name,SUM(B.value)
from    TableA A join tableB B
on A.id=B.id
group by A.id,A.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT A.name, SUM(B.value) AS sum_value
FROM   TableA A 
       INNER JOIN tableB B
          ON A.id=B.id
GROUP BY A.id;
```